# Why some apps still need a manual update although having been configured to be automatic update?

Tags: google-play-store, updates, application-autoupdate

Today I got Facebook app's update notification.

I thought I forgot to check the `automatically update` box but I didn't - it is already set for auto already.

So why the app still need our manual update?

Comment: The apps's permissions changed (specifically, new ones were added), so you have to approve the update.